# Can not install opencv using brew or make on mac osx

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, homebrew

I'm trying to install opencv by brew ,

but showed me the following errors.

I knew i should tap "brew tap homebrew/homebrew-science"

but it didn't work.

is there any idea , or should i show what information by what command to fix the problem quickly.

thanks~

```
[local] $ brew update
Error: Permission denied - /var/folders/wt/ffjhmkgx4292wtm22b966mdc0000gn/T/.gitignore20130904-819-fdlv65-0 or /usr/local/Library/Formula/.gitignore
[local] $ sudo brew update
Already up-to-date.
[local] $ sudo brew install opencv
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: No available formula for opencv
[local] $ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-science
Error: Already tapped!
[local] $ sudo brew tap homebrew/homebrew-science
Error: Already tapped!
[local] $ sudo brew install opencv
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: No available formula for opencv
[local] $ brew install opencv
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: No available formula for opencv
```

if I tried to make manually by the tutorial http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/
I will see the error after make -j8

```
     _ff_xvid_rate_control_uninit in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)
  "_xvid_plugin_lumimasking", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
  "_xvid_plugin_single", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.6.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: unfortunely, I can not finish the work by brew, I modify the config of ccmake and install it successfully

Answer (score 2):

I have recently encountered a similar problem building OpenCV using [brew](http://brew.sh). The central issue was that OpenCV would not build properly when building against ffmpeg (it will try to do this if ffmpeg is also installed.)

As suggested [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/221), the problem can be resolved by using the following brew command to build OpenCV, which forces an alternative version of the build environment (one of the top [troubleshooting suggestions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Troubleshooting) for brew):

```
brew install opencv --env=std
```

Hope this works for you too!